# Log4j Optional Format Modifiers and LogFilePatternReceiver Regular Expression Matching

Tags: java, regex, log4j, pattern-matching, apache-chainsaw

I am using the Log4j `LogFilePatternReceiver` class to read some simple log files and was wondering whether there is any way of telling Log4j to interpret a format modifier as optional.

For example, assume the following pattern:

```
%r [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n
```

This matches the string

```
123 [main] INFO org.apache.log4j.whatever x=8 - Just a message.
```

but not the string

```
123 [main] INFO org.apache.log4j.whatever - Just a message.
```

(i.e., same as above, but without the "x=8" part).

Is there any way of telling Log4j to match both?

On another relevant note, putting couple of additional print statements in the source code of  `LogFilePatternReceiver`, I get

```
Pattern: {%r [%t] %p %c %x - %m%n}
Regex:   {(.*?)[ ]+\[(.*?)\][ ]+(\S*\s*?)[ ]+(\S*\s*?)[ ]+(.*)[ ]+\-[ ]+(.*?)}
```

where the braces simply denote the start/end of each expression without belonging to it, just to make sure that there are no extra spaces or other characters involved. The regex is created by the `LogFilePatternReceiver`, at the end of its `initialize()` method.

Trying the regex in [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com), I get a match only for the part excluding the message, i.e. the match is, according to regexpal,

```
123 [main] INFO org.apache.log4j.whatever x=8 -
```

(with a space in the end). Apparently, the regex needs to be closed with a $ sign for the message to be included.

Am I making any mistake in the pattern definition?

Answer (score 0):

The last parentheses enclose a lazy quantifier: `.*?` means "match zero or more characters, as few as possible". This means that the empty string is a valid match (which makes sense in the other parts of your regex because there is stuff following that you don't want gobbled up by the previous part of your regex).

Use `.*` instead which means "match zero or more characters, as many as possible":

```
(.*?) +\[(.*?)\] +(\S*\s*?) +(\S*\s*?) +(.*) +- +(.*)
```

Comment: True, but I don't control that regex, it is generated by the LogFilePatternReceiver class of Log4j. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this LogFormat for your LogFilePatternReceiver (note the * wildcard)

PROP(RELATIVETIME) [THREAD] LEVEL LOGGER*PROP(X) - MESSAGE